# Adafruit_SSD1306 не работает на плате NodeMCU

Tags: arduino, esp8266, spi

Пытаюсь скомпилировать проект для платы NodeMCU - выдаёт ошибку. Компилировал для Arduino NANO - всё нормально. Даже при компиляции тестового скетча выдаёт тоже самое. Как быть?

```
E:\Users\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_BusIO\Adafruit_SPIDevice.cpp: In member function 'void Adafruit_SPIDevice::transfer(uint8_t*, size_t)':
E:\Users\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_BusIO\Adafruit_SPIDevice.cpp:99:31: error: no matching function for call to 'SPIClass::transfer(uint8_t*&, size_t&)'
     _spi->transfer(buffer, len);
                               ^
E:\Users\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_BusIO\Adafruit_SPIDevice.cpp:99:31: note: candidate is:
In file included from E:\Users\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_BusIO/Adafruit_SPIDevice.h:1:0,
                 from E:\Users\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_BusIO\Adafruit_SPIDevice.cpp:1:
E:\Users\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.3.0\libraries\SPI/SPI.h:64:11: note: uint8_t SPIClass::transfer(uint8_t)
   uint8_t transfer(uint8_t data);
           ^
E:\Users\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.3.0\libraries\SPI/SPI.h:64:11: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
exit status 1
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).
```

Comment: Возможно поддержка для NodeMCU ещё не до конца реализована. Попробуйте скачать версию библиотеки поновее.